# How to separate occurrences in Python groupby

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

So I am trying to create a simple pie chart to visualize political sentiment (scraping twitter). I have three categories: `negative`, `neutral`, and `positive`.
So far I have:

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style
raw_data = 'xxxxxxxx/trud.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(raw_data, index_col = 0)
test = df.groupby('sent').sent.count(). # 'sent' is a column 
print(test)
```

Output:

```
negative 178
neutral 359
positive 263
```

​
Can I separate each output and give it a variable so I can make a pie/ bar chart? `neg = negative`, `neu = neutral`, etc.
​
Thanks!

Comment: Try using `get_group` method. `test.get_group('negative')` to get the negative group.

Comment: @Sumanth I tried get_group but now getting AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'get_group'

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: If its a series object you can directly slice it `test[:1]` or `test[:3]` to get the elements of Series. Could you please post sample of your dataframe ?

Comment: Just solved it. thank you Sumanth!

Comment: Glad it helped.Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can select values of `Series` by index:

```
test = pd.Series([178, 359, 263], index=['negative','neutral','positive'])

neg = test['negative']
neu = test['neutral']
pos = test['positive']
```

But for ploting not necessary - use [`Series.plot.pie`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.plot.pie.html):

```
test.plot.pie(figsize=(3, 3))
```

[image: pic1]

Or [`Series.plot.bar`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.plot.bar.html):

```
test.plot.bar(colors=['r','b','y'])
```

[image: pic2]